# What were paper airplanes called before there were real airplanes? (i.e. untethered winged flyers, not kites or balloons)

Tags: ancient-history, aircraft, inventions, english-language, entertainment

According to the Google Ngram Viewer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer) the English word "airplane" was practically unused before the year 1900.  Given that paper is credited with having been invented over two centuries before what we know as the airplane; any paper-based flyers throughout the ages would have had to be called something other than "paper airplanes".

Is there documented evidence of the use of alternative names, in any language, and what were they?

**Note**: By paper airplane I'm referring to any invention mostly or exclusively made of flat paper (parchment, etc.) that when thrown stays aloft for longer than the same paper compressed into a ball would.

Comment: Could use a clarification: Do you know that they existed before airplanes did? The text in the question implies that you do. If so, please edit in a reference for how you know that.

Comment: Paper darts perhaps?

Comment: They would have been called paper gliders. However I cannot find anything reputable to confirm it with, therefore cannot include it in an actual answer.

Comment: [Wiki claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_plane) they go all the way back to the invention of paper in China, which predates even gliders.  Sadly, it has no references to naming

Comment: (Also, for the record, paper was invented two *millennia* before the airplane.)

Comment: @T.E.D. I've only seen anecdotal evidence that paper flyers existed before airplanes (such as Wiki as Gort points out).  But IMO it seems reasonable to assume that someone over the many centuries would've toyed with paper in that way.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Indeed that is what I meant to say.

Comment: I want to point out that in languages other than English they could be called differently, but a common term, I think, would be "paper bird" or "paper pigeon".

Comment: @GorttheRobot - From what a I saw looking this up, the Chinese were likely making something similar soon after they invented the paper. But that doesn't change the fact that the question could use an edit on this subject, with links.

Comment: @Anixx "Paper bird" would make me think of an origami bird, such as [these cranes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orizuru#/media/File:Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg).

Comment: @AndrewMorton These darts are indeed actually called  "swallows" in Czech.

Comment: In German it is still called Paper Flyer "Papierflieger".

Comment: it's just "paper darts"

Answer (score 94, accepted):

They were called paper darts in the 19th century, as evidenced in [this article](https://www.vox.com/2015/4/28/8505377/paper-airplanes-history), which contains many detailed references going back as far as 1864, and many illustrations

In fact, it appears that they continued to be called "paper darts" until the mid-20th century, when the terminology switched largely because airplanes had come to more closely resemble them.  [Early airplanes](https://www.gettyimages.com/photos/biplane?phrase=biplane&sort=mostpopular) looked nothing like paper darts.

I should add that the terminological tide may have turned definitively when [The Great International Paper Airplane Book](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/the-great-international-paper-airplane-book_jerry-mander_howard-luck-gossage/293120/item/4198171/?mkwid=URE13OvE%7cdc&pcrid=70112893392&product=4198171&plc=&pgrid=21326766312&ptaid=pla-292433097256&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_content=URE13OvE%7cdc%7cpcrid%7c70112893392%7cpkw%7c%7cpmt%7c%7cproduct%7c4198171%7cslid%7c%7cpgrid%7c21326766312%7cptaid%7cpla-292433097256%7c&gclid=Cj0KCQjwo-aCBhC-ARIsAAkNQiv0wIsRIJ55fZfImzIqzHaPvDJPsRRQ2Jts-_Y0vs-K_gs4fMVV-VMaAgGyEALw_wcB#idiq=4198171&edition=2452141) appeared in 1967.  It contained complex and fancy paper airplane designs (including a paper helicopter), and the authors used "paper dart" as a term of opprobrium for the familiar, boring design that every child learns.

[image: cover photo from thriftbooks.com]

Comment: [Andrew Dewar](https://www.facebook.com/andrew.dewar.33/photos) authors books on making and flying real-to-life paper airplanes, amongst other paper darts. [An example](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3528254913957280&set=pb.100003184191940.-2207520000..&type=3)

Answer (score 78):

### **Short Answer**

### *(Paper) Dart* and *(Paper) Arrow*

These terms were used from at least the 1860s. However, not all of these designs were what we would today recognize and call 'paper planes'. Some clearly looked like the darts thrown at dart boards.

---

### **Details**

There are 19th century references (with images resembling paper planes) to

- '**paper dart'** and **'arrow**' (UK & US sources)
- '**ein Wurfpfeil**' (a dart) (German source)
- '**flèche de papier**' (paper arrow) (French source)

---

[David Mitchell](http://www.origamiheaven.com/aboutdavidmitchell.htm), a paperfolding designer, seems to have researched this in some detail on his webpage *[The Paper Dart / The Arrow](http://www.origamiheaven.com/historyofthepaperdart.htm)*.

The image below, from a book published in 1864 but with foreword dated May 1863, is from Hermann Wagner's *'Spielbuch fur Knaben'*. In German, it was called simply ***"Ein Warfpfeil"*** [sic] (a dart).

[image]

The earliest instructions Mitchell found for making what we now know as a paper plane were in the 1864 edition of *Every Little Boy's Book* under the heading **'PAPER DART'** and with a very small picture.

In French, it was called ***"La flèche de papier"*** (the paper arrow). The image below appeared in 1880 in T de Moulidars' '*Un million de jeux et de plaisirs*'.

[image]

**'Arrow'** was also used in the New York publication '*The Kindergarten Guide*' from circa. 1882 with the following diagram:

[image]

---

It's important to note that not every 19th century reference to a 'paper dart' or 'arrow' refers to something resembling a paper plane. This is clear from the evidence presented on [Paper Darts and Flights](http://www.origamiheaven.com/historyofpaperdartsandflights.htm) where there are several illustrations which are clearly darts (sometimes including a pin in the tip), not planes. See, for example, this one:

[image]

*Image taken from The Popular Recreator, 1873*

Also, the circa. 1786 reference to a paper dart (cited in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/737jy0/did_people_make_paper_airplanes_before_the/)) by the English actor [Charles Mathews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Mathews) is inconclusive as to exactly what the then circa. 10-year-old actor-to-be was actually throwing:

> This was about the year 1786. Bishop, the  head master, wore a huge
> powdered wig, larger than any other  bishop's wig. It invited
> invasion, and we shot paper darts with  such singular dexterity into
> the protruding bush behind, that it looked like "a fretful
> porcupine."

*Source: Mrs. Mathews, '[The Life and Correspondence of Charles Mathews](https://archive.org/stream/lifecorresponden00mathrich/lifecorresponden00mathrich_djvu.txt)' (1860)*

Interestingly, [on China](http://www.origamiheaven.com/historyofpaperplanes.htm), David Mitchell states:

> It is commonly stated that paper planes originated in China over 2000
> years ago as a development of paper kites. I can find no evidence
> whatsoever to back up this assertion. It probably arises due to a
> confusion between paper planes and paper kites.

---

***All images taken from various pages on David Mitchell's 'Origami Heaven' website.***

Comment: In German it's "Wurfpfeil", in some old fonts the "a" and "u" look very similar, and "Warfpfeil" is not a word.

Comment: @knabar Noted, thanks. I'll edit with [sic] as "a" is used in the source.

Comment: The french picture shows  "La fleche de papier" (and maybe first e is è?) , not "la fleche du papier". But thanks for the laugh as it remembered me of Dexter's "omelette du fromage" :-)

Comment: @MichaëlPolla Thanks. Fixed the typo.

Comment: Great answers to a great question.  I have long wondered about this, the ability to make paper airplanes obviously preceded actual airplanes by quite a bit but I could never figure what they would be called (obviously not paper *airplanes*) and thus never found it on google.  But they are so simple that it seemed certain that someone somewhere must have worked it out, and once any schoolchild saw it demonstrated, clearly its in-class prank value would insure its illicit perpetuation forever.  The Bishop's quote above was, to me, a hilarious affirmation of my reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

"Paper darts" were the best way to have fun in the 1860s. As early as 1864, kids were flying "paper darts" that looked like what we call "paper airplanes" today.They were called paper darts because they looked and acted like "darts" to a degree of thinking.[image: diagram for assembly of paper dart; block of text describing paper darts]

Comment: Please cite image source.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The source appears to be the same as the one in Lars' answer, T de Moulidars' '*Un million de jeux et de plaisirs*', only including more of the text around the image, and apparently an English translation from the original French.

Comment: Does this answer add anything not in the other two earlier answers?

Answer (score -3):

Paper darts or paper birds or paper arrows...

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Home_Study_for_Machinists_Steam_Engineer/BIs7AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=folded%20

Comment: Link only answer is likely to be downvoted and deleted; see [advice on link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/259135). I recommend that you summarize the essential elements of the link and explain how it is different from other existing answers.